# Network interface intermittently cuts out

Tags: networking, ethernet, 22.04, interface

I recently re-imaged my 2014 Mac mini to run Ubuntu Server 22.04 and Plex. I've done similar things with earlier Mac mini models and Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 over the years, with zero issues. However, on this new setup my network interface card cuts out several times a day, and it is always when the system is performing a "heavy" task, normally transcoding video. The outage typically lasts approx. 5 minutes.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this? I've not seen any recent write-ups showing this kind of issue, but wonder if the tg3 driver itself may be the culprit? Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this? I have tried multiple known-good ethernet cables.

Here is the output from `lshw -C network`

```
description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM57766 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0f0
       version: 01
       serial: 38:c9:86:41:65:ae
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=5.15.0-39-generic duplex=full firmware=57766a-v1.15 ip=10.100.100.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:a0700000-a070ffff memory:a0710000-a071ffff
```

And here is a relevant snippet from `/var/log/syslog` correspoding to each outage. It starts with a CIFS share timing out, followed by DNS errors, and finally link down.

```
Jun 16 11:45:12 plex kernel: [34176.495211] CIFS: VFS: \\XXXXX.XXXXX.com has not responded in 180 seconds. Reconnecting...
Jun 16 11:45:29 plex systemd-resolved[646]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of UDP+EDNS0 for DNS server 10.100.99.18.
Jun 16 11:45:35 plex key.dns_resolver: XXXXX.XXXXX.com: No address associated with name
Jun 16 11:45:48 plex systemd-resolved[646]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 10.100.99.18.
Jun 16 11:45:54 plex key.dns_resolver: XXXXX.XXXXX.com: No address associated with name
Jun 16 11:47:59 plex kernel: [34343.397210] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0f0: transmit timed out, resetting
Jun 16 11:48:02 plex kernel: [34346.526916] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0f0: 0x00000000: 0x168614e4, 0x00100406, 0x02000001, 0x00800040
// a hundred or so lines like the previous one repeat with kernel hex output
Jun 16 11:48:02 plex kernel: [34346.528731] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0f0: 4: Host status block [00000001:000000ee:(0000:0000:0071):(0000:0000)]
Jun 16 11:48:02 plex kernel: [34346.528738] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0f0: 4: NAPI info [000000ee:000000ee:(0000:0000:01ff):0071:(0071:0071:0000:0000)]
Jun 16 11:48:02 plex kernel: [34346.557007] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0f0: Link is down
Jun 16 11:48:02 plex systemd-networkd[644]: enp3s0f0: Lost carrier
Jun 16 11:48:02 plex systemd-networkd[644]: enp3s0f0: DHCP lease lost
Jun 16 11:48:02 plex systemd-networkd[644]: enp3s0f0: DHCPv6 lease lost
Jun 16 11:48:02 plex systemd-timesyncd[605]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
Jun 16 11:48:06 plex kernel: [34350.267917] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0f0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
Jun 16 11:48:06 plex kernel: [34350.267932] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0f0: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
Jun 16 11:48:06 plex kernel: [34350.267937] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0f0: EEE is disabled
Jun 16 11:48:06 plex systemd-networkd[644]: enp3s0f0: Gained carrier
Jun 16 11:48:06 plex systemd-timesyncd[605]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Jun 16 11:48:10 plex systemd-networkd[644]: enp3s0f0: DHCPv4 address 10.100.100.5/24 via 10.100.100.1
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203607 "issue is also fixed when adding iommu.passthrough=1 to GRUB" Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 thank you, going to give this a try! The user has the exact same hardware, and exact same syslog error messages as I do.